# How to configure Swiftmailer to use a server using CRAM-MD5 authentication?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

The email server I am using to send mail using the Swiftmailer library has switched from a normal login to CRAM-MD5 authentication. My Swfitmailer instances no longer work with this configuration. Is there a way to set up the transport to work with CRAM-MD5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. In the transport set:

->setAuthMode('cram-md5')